# ALSA driver configuration. Is there any documentation, AT ALL?

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I am looking for a comprehensive documentation about the `alsa.conf` file that is used to configure the behavior of ALSA driver in Linux.

After exploring both the website of the ALSA project and the unofficial wiki, I can't really find at all a list of all the options that can be used in the file.

For instance, I see in the forums many people suggest this setting:
`options snd-hda`  with a bunch of options appended to it, such as some related to the keyword `dmic`.

Now, I am not asking in here what `dmic` is. I am asking, is there at all a document explaning this? I did not find any.

Answer (score 0):

In  this excellent [Ubuntu sound trouble guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure)  , in section "**Other Useful Information to Quote**" ,
 you will find 2 links to **alsa-base.conf** documentation and the possible options according sound devices models:
[HD audio models](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/sound/alsa/HD-Audio-Models.txt)
[HD audio (newer)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html)